# AES GCM no padding code in Lua file for below request body

Tags: lua, aes-gcm, kong-plugin

We need to implement AES GCM NO padding for below request body in Lua script.

{
"year":"2023",
"languageId":"2",
"city":"Banglore",
"TheatreInfo": [
{
"tId":"123",
"tname":"inox"
},
{
"tId":"124",
"tname":"inox"
}
],
"usecase":"tdetails"
}

```
type here
```

Comment: What problem do you have with implementation of the encryption?